# PowerShell 7 and AWS Module SSM: How do I actually connect?

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell

It's dead simple: How can I do the identical command to the python cli as the powershell one?
I see it returns a websocket - should I just connect?

using python/bash in mac

```
$ aws ssm start-session --target i-xxx


Starting session with SessionId: christian.bongiorno@xxx.com-0544a5b3ac9cdc6cd

sh-4.2$
```

Now in powershell on the same mac

```
PS /Users/cbongiorno/Downloads> Install-Module -Name AWS.Tools.SimpleSystemsManagement
                                                                                                                                                                     PS /Users/cbongiorno/Downloads> Start-SSMSession -Target i-xxx                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        SessionId                                            StreamUrl                                                                                                                             TokenValue                     ---------                                            ---------                                                                                                                             ----------                     christian.bongiorno@xxx.com-011bb75b5d9188ab3 wss://ssmmessages.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/data-channel/christian.bongiorno@xxx.com-011bb75b5d9188ab3?role=publish_subscribe AAEAAXDjmEubBvyBryaMbiCP5WdWX…

PS /Users/cbongiorno/Downloads> Resume-SSMSession -SessionId christian.bongiorno@xxx.com-011bb75b5d9188ab3

SessionId                                            StreamUrl                                                                                                                             TokenValue
---------                                            ---------                                                                                                                             ----------
christian.bongiorno@xxx.com-011bb75b5d9188ab3 wss://ssmmessages.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/data-channel/christian.bongiorno@sterlingts.com-011bb75b5d9188ab3?role=publish_subscribe AAEAAeHX3Op/NJ2tU4qjfsHIjS80v…
```

With powershell, I get no errors, but I also get no shell - I get this object. It should give me a terminal on that host

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: None. It simply returns this object and no session. Look at the python/cli I get an `sh-4.2$` prompt